# I need help with an assignment

Tags: java

I have been working on this programming for about 3 week now and can not figure out my mistakes.  I have to use two public classes: 1) validateLength(Number) and 2) convertIntegerToWords(Number).  My problem is that once the user inputs their integer my loop continues on forever.  The system will ask for an integer, user input, system out either too long or continue on to convertIntgerToWords.  My code is below

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Project2 {

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        //Main Method//

        //Create a Scanner//
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        //Enter an Integer//   
        System.out.print(" What is your integer ? ");
        int Number= input.nextInt(); 
        while (Number >= 0) {
            if (Number != 0)
                validateLength(Number);
            else if(Number == 0) {
                System.out.print( "Thank you for playing! " + "Good bye! ");    
                break;
            }
        }   
    }

    //Next Method//
    public static boolean validateLength(int userNum) {
        String Number = "" + userNum;
        while (userNum >= 0) {
            if (userNum < 10) 
                convertIntegerToWords(userNum);
            else if (userNum > 9){
                System.out.print("Your integer is too long !");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    //End of validate//

    //Final Method//
    public static String convertIntegerToWords(int Number) {
        if (Number == 1)
            System.out.println("Your integer " + Number + "is written out as one");
        else if (Number == 2) 
            System.out.println("Your integer " + Number + "is written out as two");
        else if (Number == 3) 
            System.out.println("Your integer " + Number + "is written out as three");
        else if (Number == 4) 
            System.out.println("Your integer " + Number + "is written out as four");
        else if (Number == 5) 
            System.out.println("Your integer " + Number + "is written out as five");
        else if (Number == 6) 
            System.out.println("Your integer " + Number + "is written out as six");
        else if (Number == 7) 
            System.out.println("Your integer " + Number + "is written out as seven");
        else if (Number == 8) 
            System.out.println("Your integer " + Number + "is written out as eight");
        else if (Number == 9) 
            System.out.println("Your integer " + Number + "is written out as nine");
            return Number + "";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to move

```
Number = input.nextInt();
```

inside of the `while` loop. Here's the typical idiom (other cleanup added as well):

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    // Enter an Integer//
    System.out.print(" What is your integer ? ");
    int Number;
    while ((Number = input.nextInt()) >= 0)
    {
        if (Number == 0)
        {
            System.out.print("Thank you for playing! " + "Good bye! ");
            break;
        }
        
        validateLength(Number);
    }
}
```

---

#### Edit

> if the user enters 0 then yes the program terminates. However if the user enters an integer 1-9, the program should spell out the integer in words (ie 1 is written out as one). It does this but it loops infinite. Same as if the user enters an integer larger than 9 it reports that the "YOur integer is too big, enter another integer" This however, repeats on the same line over and over.

That's because of the `while` loop in `validateLength()`. Try this out (note the other code cleanup as well):

```
public class ScannerDemo
{
    private static void convertIntegerToWords(int num)
    {
        String message = null;
        if (num > 9)
        {
            message = "Your integer is too long!";
        }
        else if (num > 0)
        {
            message = "Your integer " + num + " is written out as ";
            String numString = "";
            
            switch (num)
            {
                case 1:
                    numString = "one"; break;
                case 2:
                    numString = "two"; break;
                case 3:
                    numString = "three"; break;
                case 4:
                    numString = "four"; break;
                case 5:
                    numString = "five"; break;
                case 6:
                    numString = "six"; break;
                case 7:
                    numString = "seven"; break;
                case 8:
                    numString = "eight"; break;
                case 9:
                    numString = "nine"; break;
            }
            
            message += numString;
        }
        
        System.out.println(message);
    }
    
    private static int getNextNumber(Scanner s)
    {
        System.out.println("What is your integer?");
        return s.nextInt();
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        int number;
        while ((number = getNextNumber(input)) >= 0)
        {
            if (number == 0)
            {
                System.out.println("Thank you for playing! Good bye!");
                break;
            }
            
            convertIntegerToWords(number);
        }
    }
}
```

It's also [on github](https://github.com/mjball/Stack-Overflow-Q-A/blob/master/src/q6021379/ScannerDemo.java).

Comment: This works well. Thank you for your help; however, once the user inputs an integer equal to or less than 9 the program writes it out but continues forever.  I have added the return number + ""; line but still to no avail.

Comment: What is the expected behavior after the user enters a number `<= 9`? From your code, it looked like the user should be able to terminate the program by entering `0`, which is what the code in my answer allows for.

Comment: @matt... if the user enters 0 then yes the program terminates.  However if the user enters an integer 1-9, the program should spell out the integer in words (ie 1 is written out as one). It does this but it loops infinite. Same as if the user enters an integer larger than 9 it reports that the "YOur integer is too big, enter another integer" This however, repeats on the same line over and over.

Comment: @Marc: the problem is the `while` loop inside of the `validateLength()` method. However, as written in the question, `validateMethod()` does not compile. Do you mind editing your question to include the code you're now trying to run?

Comment: @Matt, can you now tell me what the difference between public static convertIntegerToWords(int), public static boolean validateLength and your private static methods.  This programming is really mind boggling!

Answer (score 0):

your while conditional is always satisfied, so it will continue to go through the while loop.  It will only stop when Number is no longer greater than or equal to zero.

you need to use some other sort of condition entirely, if you want to use a loop (although I cannot tell why you want to in this example).  You are never changing the value associated with Number, so it will always be whatever it was instantiated as.  Maybe you meant to have code that changes its value given a certain condition?  If not, you need to lose that condition entirely.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by condition.  UNderstand while (number != 0) but, if the user inputs an integer that is <= 9 the system is supposed to answer YOur INtger ** written out is *****.  Which it does but then it loops infinite

Answer (score 0):

```
while (Number >= 0) {
```

Is creating a while loop, where inside I do not see you decreasing your Number integer to stop the loop. Do you need to use a loop here? You should try an if statement instead.

Also, you may want to consider a switch statement instead of if for the output.

Comment: I thought you would need a loop statement since if the user inputs anything greater than 9 it should tell them their integer is too long and to try again. I tried the whole switch with 9 cases but that failed me too.

Comment: @Marc How many times are you interested in the user inputting something? Once, and only if it is greater than nine, repeat? Please clarify the assignment and I will try and help.

Comment: @Chalise.. I need the user to continue to enter until s/he enters a 0. The entire program should do something like this:

Comment: What is your integer?                                                   9                                                                       Your integer 9 is written out as nine                                 What is your integer?                                                10                                                                   That is to big, enter another integer                                What is your integer?                                                0                                                                    Quitting, thank you for playing

Comment: @Marc - I think you have your answer :) Glad to see it's resolved

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow.

I feel need to mention you have one class `Project2` and two methods not classes.  You get an `int` not an integer and you fail to read the next line which I suspect is your problem, unless you expect the user to type everything on the first line.

I suggest you learn to use a debugger as this can be very useful in finding debugs and understanding what your program is doing. esp for loops which don't end.

Comment: Thanks for the lesson in class and methods. I am very new to this and trying really ard to understand.  I am running eclipse but am still having trouble as well with it.

Answer (score 0):

```
//Main Method//
public static void main(String [] args) {
    //Create a Scanner//
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    bool bPlay = true; 

    while (bPlay) {
        //Enter an Integer//   
        System.out.print(" What is your integer ? ");
        int Number= input.nextInt(); 

        if (Number != 0)
        validateLength(Number);

        else if(Number == 0) {
            System.out.print( "Thank you for playing! " + "Good bye! "); 
            bPlay = false; 
            break;

        }
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  public static boolean validateLength(int userNum) {
    String Number = "" + userNum;
        while (userNum >= 0) {

    if (userNum < 10) 
    convertIntegerToWords(userNum);

    else if (userNum > 9){
    System.out.print("Your integer is too long !");
            break;
    }
  }
```

This code is responsible of the problem, you never assign userNum a new value but loop while userNum>0. This make a sweet spot for an infinite loop for number >=0 and <10. (you leave the loop ony for number>9).